# I want to display multiple icons with connecting lines between them

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, web-frontend

[image: Figma Image]

I've managed to create the layout and add the icons, but I'm struggling with creating the connecting lines between them. I've tried using CSS borders and pseudo-elements, but I can't seem to get the desired result.

Could someone please help me with a CSS-based solution or suggest an alternative approach to create these connecting lines between the icons? Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Note: This is my first question and i'm not sure if it's the right way to ask question so please feel free to modify this question.

Comment: Hi, you figma image is enormous!

Comment: WOGL is (probably) the right tech platform for icon connector lines.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=dotted+curved+lines+css+OR+svg+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Using pseudo elements with a dashed border and 50% border-radius, in combination with a clip-path that can "hide" the upper or lower half of such circles, might be one approach. The positioning and width of those circles would of course depend on how big your actual icons are, and how much space there is between them - resp. whether those are fixed, or how responsive the whole thing needs to be.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Since I'm still a beginner in web development, having a code example would be incredibly helpful for me to understand and implement this approach. If you could provide a basic example or outline of the code structure for achieving the icon connector lines using pseudo-elements, dashed borders, and clip-path, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you for your assistance! @CBroe

Comment: in stackoverflow, ppl are not gonna just hand code over to you. You need to provide the code yourself, what have you tried, where are you stuck, what error messages you get? and we can help you from there

Comment: Basically, I was thinking something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/1djLqfr9/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using SVG for the whole thing.

In fact, I believe you should be able to export all of that from Figma directly as an SVG.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I understand that using SVG might be a more straightforward approach, especially since I can export the design directly from Figma. However, I'm interested in learning more complex techniques in HTML and CSS. I believe this project will provide a great learning opportunity for me in that regard. Do you have any suggestions or resources for creating connecting lines between icons using HTML and CSS? Thank you for your help!

Comment: HTML/CSS isn't the right tool for making diagrams, but you may have some luck combining `border-radius` and conical-gradients &/or masks.